# Trying to extend HTMLInputElement prototype with some code

Tags: javascript, oop

Basically I want to add some properties and methods to input prototype, but it doesnt let me do it, the console prints error, like the prototype property is a read only one.
But I want to add few some properties and methods to it to practice prototypal inheritance with real DOM for some test task. Is there any way to do it in the prototypal style? Below is how I'm trying to achieve it

```
var input = document.getElementById("1");


function Input() {

}
Input.prototype.example = function() {
alert("Trying to extend DOM prototype");
};

HTMLInputElement.prototype = Object.create(Input.prototype);
alert(input);
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to completely replace the prototype, not extend it.

Comment: How to extend it then?

Comment: `HTMLInputElement.prototype.example = function(){}` should do your trick, but I wouldn't advice it for DOM element prototypes.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't replace `HTMLInputElement.prototype` with another object, you can only extend it like so:

```
HTMLInputElement.prototype.example = () => {
  // Your code here
};
```

Please note that extending native prototypes should be done **very** carefully and only if you really need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!